Gradle Not Showing Up in Android Studio on Ubuntu
I'm using Android Studio on Ubuntu, and I've been struggling with an issue for a while. Whenever I try to write native code in Flutter or link an SDK, I need Gradle, but it doesn’t show up in my Android Studio. Even the option File -> Sync Project with Gradle Files is not visible. Also, when I try to link an SDK to my Flutter project, the autocomplete feature for native code doesn’t work. I’ve been facing this problem for quite some time, and it’s been a big hindrance. What steps can I take to resolve this?
Thank you in advance for your help!
u use
gradle clean
gradle build
but useless
